# Can I safely delete the Mac OS X Base System Partition?

Tags: macos, recovery

I'm running El Capitan + Windows 7 on a 2011 MBP which came with Lion.

The recovery mode on my MBP is broken, it sits on about 75% of the progress bar loaded for days (I've waited 2 full days on two tries) and it never loads the recovery.

The Internet Recovery however works fine.

Can I safely delete the Mac OS X Base System partition? I think if I delete it, I won't be able to get boot back into El Capitan. How can I reinstall the recovery?

I have found this question, [Can not erase my Mac OS X base system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358598/can-not-erase-my-mac-os-x-base-system) even formatting the Mac OS X Base System seems impossible.

I have also read this question [What is the 'Mac OS X Base System' disk image on my 2011 MacBook AIr?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22941/what-is-the-mac-os-x-base-system-disk-image-on-my-2011-macbook-air).

I also need to install a Lion copy on an external HDD.

When I boot into Internet Recovery mode, it puts me to a High Sierra Internet Recovery which will install HS. This is because I have El Capitan installed. I want to delete the Mac OS X Base System so that on next boot, I can be put on a Lion Internet Recovery.

Comment: As explained in the linked question you can’t erase the Base System because it’s not real. It’s created temporarily  in RAM whilst in Recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin Hello, Are you sure? Because in that question, the `disk0` is the Mac OS and `disk1` is the Base System. An I'm going to quote the rest: `So that's disk0 and disk1; what about the rest? I'm not certain, but I'm pretty sure they are RAM disks` So he is talking about `disk2` to `disk12`. So the answer does not imply that Base System is a RAM disk. But if you're saying this from your own knowledge that the Base System is indeed a RAM disk, then ok